# Java ArrayList remove method polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

im using an `ArrayList<Integer>` and i've noticed there are two remove methods:

the one that is inharited from `List` interface:

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

And one implemented in `ArrayList`:

```
public Object remove(int index)
```

in my case when i'll call `list.remove(2);`, which method will be called? and why? since my "object" is also an integer...

Thanks.

Comment: This is sort of a spurious question, since a simple test would have answered the question in about a minute.

Comment: Thomas beat me to it - when unsure of something simple like this, try it.  Write out a simple program to see what the result is.  It would have taken you roughly the same amount of time as posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Charles Goodwin beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter The question as to which function is called could be answered in a minute but the question as to why still needs to be answered.

Comment: @bstick12 : In this case, compiler makes the most specific call, which is indeed the call to int index. See my answer.

Comment: @roadrunner I did see your answer and I already knew the answer. My comment was more about the question and Thomas's comment. The questioner obviously didn't know why remove(int) would be called and that couldn't be answered by experimentation.

Comment: Guys, sure i could test it (and i did), but i still wanted an answer for the "why" part, so iv'e posted them both...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the method like this:

```
intList.remove(2);
```

the second item will be removed.
If you call the method like this:

```
intList.remove(new Integer(2)));
```

the object 2 will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Object remove(int index)
```

will be called.

Since you are calling `list.remove(2)`, the parameter is of type int. So the method the most specific matching value gets the call, in this case, the `remove(int index)` and the value at `index` will be removed

Comment: I would add that this inconsistency is the result of the java collections api redesign.

Comment: OK, if i need the other method to be called, can i do it somehow? maybe upcast it to List so the other method will be the "most specific" one?

Comment: @Boris C: or you could pass `Integer.valueOf(2)`.

Comment: @Boris C - No, the other form of the method is for when you have an instance of an object that you want to remove from the list but do not know where in the list it is.

Comment: @Boris C - Fair enough but if you have an Integer(2) then using remove(2) still won't work because the compiler will see the '2' as an int and always remove the element at that index. What you propose will work as long as the target object's equals() method behaves properly.

Comment: it woks...remove(new Integer(2)) removes the element 2, and not the element with index 2...

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDocs on ArrayList.remove(Object obj) :

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is
>   unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i
>   such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an
>   element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified
>   element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the
>   call).

Since it uses o.equals(), it requires the contained elements to A) be an object, and B) be equal to the remove() argument.

Here is a sample to demonstrate.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package ksf;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Kelly French
 *
 */
public class ListRemove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();

        l.add(new Integer(0)); // to take up the zeroth spot
        l.add(new Integer(300)); // 1st added, position [1]
        l.add(new Integer(100)); // 2nd added, position [2]
        l.add(new Integer(200)); // 3rd added, position [3]

        // will remove whatever is at location 2, i.e. Integer(100)
        l.remove(2); 

        // will remove first object Integer(200) if it exists
        //  in this case it is the equivalent of l.remove(3);
        l.remove(new Integer(200));

        // will cause nothing to be removed
        l.remove(200); // no 200th element in the list
        l.remove(new Integer(2)); // no element passes o.equals()
    }
}
```